# Xamarin Forms ListView item Command not binding to ICommand in VM

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin-forms-4

I have a ContentPage that has a ListView. Within the DataTemplate of the ListView is a TextCell that holds a string value that I have binded in the corresponding ViewModel. I have the command for said TextCell binded to an ICommand in my ViewModel. When I load up an emulator, and -click- a cell item, nothing happens. I don't hit my breakpoint I have in my ViewModel on the binded ICommand. Is there something I am missing? Disclaimer: I had stepped away from Xamarin for a while.

View:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding matchupList}" >
    
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <TextCell Text="{Binding matchup}" Detail="{Binding matchupDescription}"  Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" /> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class GamesByDate : ContentPage
{   
    public GamesByDate ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new GamesByDateViewModel(Navigation);
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand SelectedCommand => new Command(async () => await GotoPage2());
public async Task GotoPage2()
    {
        try
        {
           //DoSomething

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

    }
```

Once again, my mission is to tap an item in the ListView, trigger ICommand, calls another method in VM. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a relative binding.  The BindingContext of each row is NOT the VM, it is the current element of the ItemsSource

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you could use [Relative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0). Try the following code:

```
<DataTemplate>
 <TextCell Text="{Binding matchup}" Detail="{Binding matchupDescription}"  Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPageViewModel}}, Path=SelectedCommand}" /> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Hope it works.